# What does casting/assertion in parenthesis before brackets mean in TypeScript code?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Here's a bit of code I was looking over (I'm new to TypeScript):

```
    // Set up decorator
    const proxy = Object.create(null) as ts.LanguageService;
    const oldLS = info.languageService;

    for (const k in oldLS) {
        (<any>proxy)[k] = function () {
            return (<any>oldLS)[k].apply(oldLS, arguments);
        }
    }
```

Look at this part of the code:

```
        (<any>proxy)[k] = function () {
            return (<any>oldLS)[k].apply(oldLS, arguments);
        }
```

Why is casting needed on `(<any>proxy)[k]` since aren't all objects accessible via the bracket notation? And furthermore, why is the above assignment not simply written as: `(<any>proxy)[k] = (<any>oldLS)[k];` (what is this code trying to accomplish)?

Comment: Regarding your second question: because it would need to be `(<any>proxy)[k] = oldLS[k].bind(oldLS);` at least

Comment: Ah, because you exchange `this` context when you assign it. So it's a way to prevent this exchange and keep the context in `oldLS`. But yeah, you wrote a shorter version.

Comment: (<any>proxy)[k] - Here we have to cast proxy to any, because if you see the initialization of proxy, it is just simple object and when you see the usage of proxy, it is used as an enumerable object. If you do not cast it to any it will throw an error.

Comment: So in typescript you are not allowed to access properties on simple objects via the bracket notation? Why not cast it as enumerable instead of `any`?

Comment: If you use square bracket notation with any object it means it is of type array. In your example it is not. You can access properties of object without casting them, but in this case, oldLS is an array so at the end of loop you will have only oldLS's last index properties into proxy.

Comment: But oldLS doesn't look like it is an array since it's being casted as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the face of it, it sounds like you're asking us to explain why some unknown person might have performed a type assertion in some unspecified TypeScript code for some unspecified TypeScript version.  Not sure how someone could really help you there.

But luckily the magic of search engines has divined that you're referring to [this tutorial](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/Writing-a-Language-Service-Plugin#decorator-creation) for writing your own language service plugin in TypeScript, written by [@RyanCavanaugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1704166/ryan-cavanaugh).

---

The reason seems to be that the key `k` is being inferred as `string`, and not as `keyof ts.LanguageService`, so the compiler rejects indexing into `proxy` and `oldLS` with `k`, unless you do some sort of assertion.

I'm not exactly sure *why* this is happening; I think that since TypeScript v2.1.4, the variable `a` in `for a in b` [should have the type `keyof typeof b`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12314).

For example:

```
function hmm<T>(t: T): void {  
  for (const k in t) { // k is inferred as keyof T
    const keyofT: keyof T = k; // no error
  }
}
```

But in the code you included it infers only as `string`, for some reason ( maybe someone in the know can explain).

Once TypeScript fails to infer something you yourself know to be true, you can usually force the compiler to bend to your will by an annotation (in the case of [bivariant parameters](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-function-parameters-bivariant)), or a type assertion.

In my case, I'd probably have done this instead:

```
    type K = keyof ts.LanguageService
    for (const k in oldLS) {
      proxy[k as K] = function() {
        return oldLS[k as K].apply(oldLS, arguments);
      }
    }
```

but that's a judgment call.

Hope that helps; good luck.

Comment: `for a in b` does not have the type `keyof typeof b`, because it [wouldn't be very sound](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/12253#issuecomment-263132208). Here's a simple example that doesn't type check: [link](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Foo%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Adeclare%20var%20foo%3A%20Foo%3B%0D%0Adeclare%20function%20test(key%3A%20keyof%20Foo)%3A%20void%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Afor%20(const%20k%20in%20foo)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20test(k)%3B%20%20%20%0D%0A%7D).

Comment: I agree, but soundness isn't the only consideration in TypeScript.  For example, see the function `hmm()` I added above.  That type checks, even though I could do `const a = { foo: 'hey', bar: 'you' }; hmm<{ foo: string }>(a);` which is unsound.  I'm not sure why the `keyof typeof b` inference is okay for generics and not okay for concrete types... pragmatism, compromise, or an actual bug somewhere.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks for the explanation! Yeah I've been looking over the code for working with language services in VS Code editor but I thought the snippet had enough context by itself.

Answer (score 3):

I guess *RyanCavanaugh* would be the best person to answer this if the snippet is taken from his [sample-ts-plugin](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh/sample-ts-plugin) repo, but I'll take a stab at it anyway.

> What does the casting on (<any>proxy)[k] accomplish since it is on the left side of the assignment?

It casts the variable `proxy` to `any` *before* the property `k` is accessed.
This is to ignore compiler errors (I assume).

> aren't all objects accessible via the bracket notation?

Not if [noImplicitAny](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/options/noImplicitAny.html) compiler option is on.

Try to toggle the `noImplicitAny` option in [this example](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Foo%20%7B%20a%3A%20string%3B%20%7D%0D%0Aconst%20proxy%20%3D%20Object.create(null)%20as%20Foo%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20key%3A%20string%20%3D%20'b'%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Aproxy%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%205%3B%0D%0A(%3Cany%3Eproxy)%5Bkey%5D%20%3D%205%3B).

> (what is this code trying to accomplish)?

It's taking an existing function from the original `info.languageService` and exposing it as a method of `proxy`. 
As noted in the comments, `(<any>proxy)[k] = (<any>oldLS)[k];` might not work correctly because the original function would be called with a wrong `this` context.

*Bergi*'s shorter `(<any>proxy)[k] = oldLS[k].bind(oldLS);` version would work in any project where programmer sanity is maintained, but it *could* "fail" to call the correct function if `oldLs[k]` method was initialized lazily or changed later.